# how to send a plain http request to a url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-requests

I have an HTTP request generated with postman:

```
GET http://google.com/ HTTP/1.1
cache-control: no-cache
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.3.0
Accept: */*
Host: google.com
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

I'm receiving these types of HTTP requests from a client via socket in python and I want to send it to its specified URL.

I'm familiar with requests library but considering the fact that the client may send any type of HTTP request, it seems inefficient to break down the request and rebuild it.

is there any easy and convenient way to send this request directly to its URL?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Use [TCP Socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example).

Comment: could you please clarify your question? On one hand "predetermined" suggests requests are somehow always the same, on the other hand it looks like you want to build some sort of proxy.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, I meant that I have the request as a text, it is not always the same. yes it's some sort of proxy.

Comment: just get the raw request and send it to other place, you can do it by using `socket`  `asyncio`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently one way that we can achieve this is by using TCP socket as mentioned in the comments, it can be done like this:

```
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
port = 80
try:
    server_socket.connect((url,port))
    server_socket.send(str.encode(body)) # encoding needed for streaming in bytes
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))
    sys.exit(1)
```

as a side note, url must not include 'http://' or 'https://'. if so it raises an error. This was the main reason that my code was not working initially.